# Removing all but letters and number, replacing spaces. PHP Regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to prepare a string for use as a directory listing. I am working with user entered titles and need to remove all but letters and numbers, then replace spaces with `_`.. I have been able to get somewhat close to this with `preg_replace` but don't have hours to learn the ins and outs of Regex at the moment.

Here is an example of the string = `This is a -string- that has /characters & other stuff! Let's filter it`. What I am shooting for is:
`this_is_a_string_that_has_characters_other_stuff_lets_filter_it`

I was able to get close with this code, but places where a character was removed the space after it remained. The result was double _'s, which is acceptable but not what I was shooting for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my attempt:

```
<?php
$string = " This is a -string- that has /characters & other stuff! Let's filter it?";
$cleansedstring = trim($string);
$cleansedstring = strtolower($cleansedstring);
$cleansedstring = preg_replace('/[^ \w]+/', '', $cleansedstring);
$cleansedstring = preg_replace('[\s]', '_', $cleansedstring);
echo $cleansedstring;
?>
```

**UPDATED**
Here is what I have figured out from some suggestions on here, seems pretty clean and outputs the string I was shooting for.. suggestions on improvement?

```
$string = " This is a -string- _that has /characters & other stuff! Let's filter it?23";
$cleansedstring = trim($string);
$cleansedstring = strtolower($cleansedstring);
$cleansedstring = preg_replace('/[^ \pL \pN]/', '', $cleansedstring);
$cleansedstring = preg_replace('[\s+]', '_', $cleansedstring);
echo $cleansedstring;
```

Comment: Letters are `\pL`.  Numbers are `\pN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex for removing unwanted characters should not have a `+` there, and the one that checks for spaces needs a `+` after it.

Comment: Aha! Exactly what I was looking for.. how would I combine these two into one `preg_replace()`?

Comment: The `+` in the first regex is okay, but adding a `+` to the second regex is what solves the problem.  @NightMICU, I think you should accept this answer.  (And no, you can't combine them into one regex.)

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

```
$s = "This is a -string- that has /characters & other stuff!    Let's filter it";
echo "ORIG: [{$s}]<br />";
$s = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]/","",$s);
$s = preg_replace("/\s[\s]+/"," ",$s);
$s = preg_replace("/\s/","_",$s);
$s = strtolower($s);
echo "NEW: [{$s}]<br />";

// output is
// ORIG: [This is a -string- that has /characters & other stuff! Let's filter it]
// NEW: [this_is_a_string_that_has_characters_other_stuff_lets_filter_it]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an old function I have - slightly modified to use underscores:

```
public function make_url_friendly($string)
{
    $string = trim($string);

    // weird chars to nothing
    $string = preg_replace('/(\W\B)/', '',  $string);

    // whitespaces to underscore
    $string = preg_replace('/[\W]+/',  '_', $string);

    // dash to underscore
    $string = str_replace('-', '_', $string);

    // make it all lowercase
    $string = strtolower($string);

    return $string; 
}
```

This should do what you need

Comment: It's torn from something else where I have options - hence it being split up

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but when I tried this out I ended up with `_this_is_a__string__that_has_characters_other_stuff_let_s_filter_it_`..

Comment: I've edited and moved the order around - you *should* have fewer underscores all over the place now. (Again, I had to rip a lot out for it to be useful here, so might need the odd tweak :) )

Comment: This has been bugging me. +1 for the effort and sharing your code. I opted to go with the selected answer because it only took a minimal change from what I already had to get the desired results. But seeing the -1 didn't seem fair, since this produced the same result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$string = " This is a -string- that has /characters & & other stuff! Let's filter it?";
$cleanstring = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('#\W+#', '_', $string), '_'));
```